# How Process builder schedule actions works

Tags: scheduled-apex, process-builder, schedule

I have few schedule actions of Process Builder. The process is going to fire based on one Boolean record when that made true. I scheduled 100 days before expiry date. Now if i want change expiry date to future date or past date. What will happen in this scenario.Can any please make me understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the referenced field value and the schedule hasn’t been processed, Salesforce recalculates the schedule associated with that field.
If Salesforce recalculates the schedule to a date in the past, Salesforce executes the associated actions shortly after you save the record. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_limits_scheduled.htm&language=en_US