# Scheduled action in process builder

Tags: process-builder

Do the scheduled action define in process builder execute even when entry criteria is false?
Like I'm facing problem I have scheduled a action to 90 days on the updation of record and entry criteria is met, but when scheduled time comes and entry criteria is false then also scheduled action is get execute.

Does schedule action evaluate before execution? i.e. does it checks entry criteria before it gets execute or only execution is happened no criteria is been checked?

Comment: This previous question and answer may help you http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113697/how-process-builder-schedule-actions-works

Answer (score 2):

If you change the referenced field value and the schedule hasn’t been processed, Salesforce recalculates the schedule associated with that field.  This includes removing the scheduled item if it no longer meets the requirements.

You can test this by triggering the flow and creating a scheduled action.  Then find your scheduled action in the paused and waiting interviews section under Flows in Setup.  Now, change your record that triggered the flow so it no longer meets the requirements.  You should see the pending scheduled action removed.

[Process Scheduled Actions Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled.htm&language=en_US&type=0)